Is "Asia's largest-class" acceptable as a phrase?
If a film event is one of the largest of its kind in Asia, is it correct to call it "Asia's largest-class film event"?
I meant to say the event is one of Asia's largest film festivals in terms of visitors, exhibitors, impact and so on. It is not that the event is classified by size, such as small-sized movies and large-sized movies.

Please use that phrase in a full sentence. It is not clear what you mean by "call it".

What exactly is a film event? A film showing? A film premiere?

A film festival

No native English speaker would use that term. Class has several meanings but generally it applies to a group of things or people. So largest class is the biggest of the known groups of something, such as "largest class in the school".
I think what you mean to say is

The film event is [one of the] largest in Asia.

Or if you are talking about classes (types) of film event

The film event is the largest of its type in Asia.

or

The film event is the largest in its class in Asia.


I'm guessing the OP was extrapolating from something like "world-class".

film event? i.e. premiere?

@Lambie Could be, but film festivals (Cannes, Sundance) are also events.

If Asian film-events are organized into classes according to size like T-shirts:

Small Asian film-events
Medium Asian film-events
Large Asian film-events
Extra-large Asian film-events
XXL Asian film-events

and a particular Asian film-event falls into the XXL class, you could say

This Asian film-event is in the largest class of Asian film events.

It would even be grammatical (though not idiomatic) to say:

This largest-class Asian film-event has attracted 300,000 people.

Just as it would be grammatical to say of an XXL T-shirt:

This largest-size cotton T-shirt shrank in the dryer.

What makes it awkward and unidiomatic is that you're  referring to the class not by its name or designation but by its relative size on the scale. This would be idiomatic:

This XXL Asian film-event attracted 300,000 people.
This XXL cotton T-shirt shrank in the dryer.

P.S. Some speakers would say the letters "[ex ex el]" and some would say the words "extra extra large".
